# Am I crazy? Help with NSFileManager delegate method shouldProceedAfterError in 10.5+

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsfilemanager

So I'm kind of a Cocoa n00b, but I'm writing this simple little program and I can't get the NSFileManager delegate method "shouldProceedAfterError..." to fire. Here's the code I'm running in my AppDelegate

```
-(BOOL)copyFile {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] setDelegate:self];

    NSError *copyError = nil;
    NSString *filename = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[self.sourceFile path] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] lastObject]];
    NSString *destination = [[[[[UserData sharedData] folderLocation] path] stringByAppendingString:@"/"] stringByAppendingString:filename];

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:[self.sourceFile path] toPath:destination error:&copyError];

    NSLog(@"error! %@",copyError);

    [filename release];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)fileManager:(NSFileManager *)fileManager shouldProceedAfterError:(NSError *)error copyingItemAtPath:(NSString *)srcPath toPath:(NSString *)dstPath {
    NSLog(@"more error... %@",error);
    return NO;
}
- (BOOL)fileManager:(NSFileManager *)fileManager shouldCopyItemAtPath:(NSString *)srcPath toPath:(NSString *)dstPath {
    NSLog(@"in shouldCopyItemAtPath...");
    return YES;
}
```

The situation I'm trying to deal with is if the file already exists at the destination. I do get an error, but I never get that "more error..." trace to output. I also DO get that trace from shouldCopyItemAtPath: so I'm not exactly sure why the method isn't firing?

Am I going crazy, how did I mess up the delegate implementation here? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a hypothesis, but since copyItemAtPath:toPath:error is defined such that *"The file specified in srcPath must exist, while dstPath must not exist prior to the operation."*, perhaps the scenario where dstPath already exists isn't considered an "error," and so doesn't fire the delegate.

i.e. perhaps *"It's not an error if you do something we told you not to do."*

You can always do the check and delete it yourself:

```
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

// Delete the file if it already exists.
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: destination])
        if (![fileManager removeItemAtPath: destination error: error])
                return NO;

return [fileManager copyItemAtPath: source toPath: destination error: error];
```

Comment: "It's not an error if you do something we told you not to do."

doh. I must've totally missed that part. I was hoping I could implement some kind of modal window in the delegate method, but you're right I just need to check before I start the copy. Thanks for the response! I'd vote up but I don't have any rep :(

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are providing a wrong path as source?
`copyItemAtPath` does not call the delegate methods if the the source path is invalid.
You can test that if you use the following method:

```
-(IBAction)copyFile:(id)sender
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] setDelegate:self];
    NSError* copyError = nil;
    NSString* sourceFilepath = [@"~/Desktop/source.txt" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
    NSString* targetFilepath = [@"~/Desktop/target.txt" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];  
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:sourceFilepath toPath:targetFilepath error:&copyError];  
    NSLog(@"Error:%@", copyError);  
}
```

When calling that method I notice the following behavior:

- If ~/Desktop/source.txt is a file and ~/Desktop/target.txt does not exist:

  - NSFileManager calls the `shouldCopyItemAtPath` delegate method
- If ~/Desktop/source.txt is a file and ~/Desktop/target.txt exists:

  - NSFileManager first calls the `shouldCopyItemAtPath` and `shouldProceedAfterError`
- If ~/Desktop/source.txt does not exist

  - NSFileManager does not call any delegate method and just returns a NSError objet